# Jenkins: define environment variable with another variable

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to define a variable for my node, but I want that this variable includes the EXECUTOR_NUMBER value, as in the picture:

[image: Jenkins]

However, this is working as a normal string, and doesn't substitute the value of the variable EXECUTOR_NUMBER. I am seeing "ci-db#$EXECUTOR_NUMBER" instead of "ci-db#0" Does anyone know if this is even possible? (Jenkins version  2.361.1)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

If you want to have a database for your CI builds, consider the following options first:

- use [TestContainers](https://testcontainers.com/);
- spin up a container with the database during the build with Docker/Podman Compose (or even minikube - depending on your setup) or Groovy (using [Docker plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)).

If you still want to use a database deployed to an agent or somewhere else, and it has schema names having numerical indexes (or the database name(s) itself), you can just define the environment variable in your Jenkinsfiles:

```java
pipeline {
  // ...
  environment {
    TEST_DB_NAME = "ci-db#$env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER"
  {
  // ...
}
```

You might also want to look into [Lockable resources](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/) plugin in this case.